# Check three radio buttons automatically on load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three radio button lists, and I would like the first option of each to be selected when the page loads. The options are populated based on MySQL retrieval queries.

Currently, only the first element of the first radio button list is checked. I am struggling to get the first element of the other two lists to be checked on load.

```
<ul id="radio" class="input-list">
    <?php
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id, name, price FROM cases ORDER BY price");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($case_id, $case_name, $case_price);
        while($stmt->fetch()) 
        {
            echo 
            '<li>
                <input id="'.$case_id.'" name="config-prod" value="'.$case_id.'" type="radio">
                <label class="sub-label" for="'.$case_id.'">'.$case_name.'    [£'.$case_price.']</label>
            </li>';
        }
        $stmt->close();
        ?>
        </ul>

        <ul id="radio" class="input-warranty">
            <?php
                $stmt18 = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id, name, price FROM warranty ORDER BY price");
                $stmt18->execute();
                $stmt18->bind_result($warranty_id, $warranty_name, $warranty_price);
                while($stmt18->fetch()) 
                {
                    echo 
                    '<li>
                        <input id="'.$warranty_id.'" name="config-warranty" value="'.$warranty_id.'" type="radio">
                        <label class="sub-label" for="'.$warranty_id.'">'.$warranty_name.'    [£'.$warranty_price.']</label>
                    </li>';
                }
                $stmt18->close();
            ?>
        </ul>

        <ul id="radio" class="input-build">
        <?php
            $stmt19 = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id, name, price FROM buildtime ORDER BY price");
            $stmt19->execute();
            $stmt19->bind_result($buildtime_id, $buildtime_name, $buildtime_price);
            while($stmt19->fetch()) 
            {
                echo 
                '<li>
                    <input id="'.$buildtime_id.'" name="config-build" value="'.$buildtime_id.'" type="radio">
                    <label class="sub-label" for="'.$buildtime_id.'">'.$buildtime_name.'    [£'.$buildtime_price.']</label>
                </li>';
            }
        $stmt19->close();
    ?>
</ul>
```

I have used javascript to get the first option of the first radio button list to be checked on load:

```
<script>
        document.querySelector("#radio li input").checked = true;   
</script>
```

How can I make the first element of the second and third lists to be selected on load? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use same `id` attribute on different elements. Instead, you can create a custom class like `my-radio` and then get all the elements with `document.querySelectorAll(".my-radio li input")`, to finally iterate over the elements and set the `checked` property of each one.

Comment: That really should be done on the server by setting the *checked* attribute on the first radio button of each set.

Comment: I would mix as little HTML with PHP as possible, with the exception of page builds *(if you must)*, which it looks like this is. I would use PHP for getting and setting MySQL using mysqli or PDO. Set your page up as much as possible with the HTML, then AJAX in what you need as you need it. Use external CSS and JavaScript so they are cached, keeping in mind upon deployment, change your file names or use the get url technique when changing your files. Just comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In continuation with RobG's comment:

```
...
$isFirst = true;
while($stmt->fetch()) {
  echo '<li>
    <input id="'.$case_id.'" name="config-prod" value="'.$case_id.'" type="radio"'.$isFirst?' checked':''.'>
    <label class="sub-label" for="'.$case_id.'">'.$case_name.'         [£'.$case_price.']</label>
  </li>';
  $isFirst = false;
}
...

$isFirst = true;
while($stmt18->fetch()) {
  echo '<li>
    <input id="'.$warranty_id.'" name="config-warranty" value="'.$warranty_id.'" type="radio"'.$isFirst?' checked':''.'>
    <label class="sub-label" for="'.$warranty_id.'">'.$warranty_name.'         [£'.$warranty_price.']</label>
  </li>';
  $isFirst = false;
}
...
```

BTW, on side note, it would be better to write a function to generate a checkbox and reuse that function for different loops ;). For example, the below code is more readable.

```
function echoCheckbox($property, $id, $name, $price, $checked){
  echo '<li>
    <input id="'.$id.'" name="'.$property.'" value="'.$id.'" type="radio"'.$checked?' checked':''.'>
    <label class="sub-label" for="'.$id.'">'.$name.'[£'.$price.']</label>
  </li>';
}
...
$isFirst = true;
while($stmt->fetch()) {
  echoCheckbox("config-prod", $case_id, $case_name, $case_price, $isFirst);
  $isFirst = false;
}
...

$isFirst = true;
while($stmt18->fetch()) {
  echoCheckbox("config-warranty", $warranty_id, $warranty_name, $warranty_price, $isFirst);
  $isFirst = false;
}
...
```